# How to draw texture from imputProcessor class? LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I try drawing stuff using *InputProcessor* class of LibGDX. But nothing is drawn! Can I draw textures from any other place rather than **render ()** class in LibGDX?

And yes, if I draw in **render ()** class it is drawn ok, but can I draw from somewhere else, like *InputProcessor* touchDragged?

here is my code

```
public class mm_imput implements InputProcessor {

 SpriteBatch batch=new SpriteBatch();
 Texture pixel=new Texture("something.png");

   @Override
   public boolean touchDragged (int x, int y, int pointer) {

      drawSomething();

   }
   void drawSomething() {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(pixel, 100, 100, 100, 100);
        batch.end();
    }
```

}

It should be showing something every time I drag mouse.. How to achieve this?

Comment: I think the solution proposed by Phil Royer is good, call to InputProcessor  is called every frame before rendering method, you can read in the header of the interface,
`An InputProcessor is used recibir input events from the keyboard and the touch screen (mouse on the desktop). For This It
  * Have to be registered with the {link Input # setInputProcessor (InputProcessor)} method. It will be called each frame before the
  * Call to {link ApplicationListener # render ()}.`

Comment: Did you ever hear about the simplest design pattern - MVC? I don't mean that you should design your code only with this pattern but drawing something in InputProcessor is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Batch has to be in the Render method of a Screen class.

At this link you'll see what I'm talking about: https://github.com/littletinman/Hype/blob/master/Hype/core/src/com/philiproyer/hype/screens/Details.java

I have a main screen class, with a Render method. I'm implementing the InputProcessor interface.

What I recommend is having the Render method in a condition for when the touch is down.

```
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 1); // Clear the screen with a solid color
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(isTouching == true) { // check for touching
      batch.begin();
        batch.draw(pixel, 100, 100, 100, 100);
      batch.end();
    }
}
```

Then, in the touchDown method add something like this

```
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    isTouching = true; // Set boolean to true
    return false;
}
```

To make sure you have it reset when you stop touching do the following in your touchUp method

```
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    isTouching = false; // Set boolean to false
    return false;
}
```

Let me know if anything isn't quite clear. Best of luck!

Comment: So is it a *must* for Batch always to in be Render method? It *can't* be drawn from somewhere else?

Comment: Well, if you clear the screen in your render method then everything you've drawn before that (which includes your input listener) will be cleared as well. Strictly speaking it isn't a *must* (you dont have to clear the screen in the render method), but it sure would be over complicating *not* to render in the render method (or any methods called within the render method).